# I imported my Android contacts to Google contacts, and now they are all duplicated

Tags: contacts, google-contacts, import, vcard

I was under the impression my Android contacts are not syncing with my Google contact list, but after importing them to Google contacts they are all duplicated in Android.

Any tips how to undo this mess?

Comment: You need to access your G mail account from PC and remove duplicate . Then delete all contracts on your Android . Next carry out a sync

Comment: Ah, I see. Will try. Thx. Luckily, Gmail Contacts are not duplicated. Just the phone number contacts on Android were dupe synced from some reason, after importing them to Google Contacts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you're contacts are duplicated by logging on to google on a browser...

If they are duplicated there then that means the back up screwed up...

If they are not duplicated there, then, delete all your contacts on your phone then back up from google again.

Hope I helped,

Sid